# Create a Grouped DataFrame from a QUERY not a Field List

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I need help. I'm going to try to summarize it.

Here is a DataFrame for example:

```python
df = pd.DataFrame(
      {
        "Name": ["Jai", "Anuj", "Jai", "Princi", "Gaurav", "Anuj", "Princi", "Abhi"],
        "Age": [27, 24, 22, 32, 33, 36, 27, 32],
        "Address": ["Nagpur", "Kanpur", "Allahabad", "Kannuaj", "Jaunpur", "Kanpur", "Allahabad", "Aligarh"],
        "Qualification": ["Msc", "MA", "MCA", "Phd", "B.Tech", "B.com", "Msc", "MA"]
      }
    )
```

```
     Name  Age    Address Qualification
0     Jai   27     Nagpur           Msc
1    Anuj   24     Kanpur            MA
2     Jai   22  Allahabad           MCA
3  Princi   32    Kannuaj           Phd
4  Gaurav   33    Jaunpur        B.Tech
5    Anuj   36     Kanpur         B.com
6  Princi   27  Allahabad           Msc
7    Abhi   32    Aligarh            MA
```

Lets says you performed a `groupby` function for this

```python
grp = df.groupby('Name')
grp.get_group('Jai')
```

To filter out all the records with Name= "Jai"

Could this be possible to manipulate the dataframe when the source is coming from a WHERE clause in SQL?

For example

```sql
SELECT DATE, TOTAL$, TOTAL# FROM TABLE
WHERE SALESREP= 'JAI'
```

Let's say in the event that Sales Rep is NOT a column on the Dataframe.

Comment: Why not query before grouping: `df.query("Name == 'Jai'").groupby('Name')`? But this seems redundant to group by one value.

Answer (score 0):

In pandas, use the loc method.

```
df.loc[df['Name'] == 'Jai']
```

I ran this code on a databricks spark cluster.

[image]

If you have access to a spark cluster, then create a dataframe and use Spark SQL.  It will give you the ANSI SQL look and feel you want.

PS:  You can also create hive tables for files that have a known format.  Even easier.  This is call schema on read.